# print_r returns all mysql results but json_encode returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would want to return some information from a database. The Problem when the query is executed in MySQL it works fine but when I run the same Query in PHP , it does not work. It only works if I set a limit to less than 9. Any thing 9 and above returns a blank screen. My table currently has over 40 rows.

When I initiate a print_r($results). All rows are returned but with json_encode($results), it returns blank screen and only returns if there is a limit of 8.

```
ini_set("display_errors",1);
$Db = new PDO ( "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=recycle",'root','' );
$Db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$Query = $Db->prepare('SELECT * FROM recyclable');

$Query->execute();

$Results = $Query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

echo json_encode($Results); [error]
//print_r($Results) works.
```

I have deleted the database and tried it again.Still not working and even tested the same query against other database tables and still not working.

Just can't stress on how much frustration this is causing me.
I am using XAMPP

1.8.3  [PHP: 5.5.3]

Comment: The problem is related to non-ASCII characters but I do not yet know the solution

Answer (score 2):

it can be because of "out of memory" problem.. just do an

`ini_set("display_errors",1)"` in the beginning and `E_ALL` error

Comment: Still not working. I have restarted my computer. Tested this is multiple browsers and still get the same error.

Comment: Can you explain the out of memeory problem? it is my physical memory in my PC is out of memory or what? Cos my physical memory is 3gb and no process is currently running.

Comment: sure. php has some maximum memory allowed... you might wanna change that: help: https://drupal.org/node/207036

Comment: Still not working. I have changed the memory limit to 500M but still the problem persist. I have uninstalled XAMPP and reinstalled it and still. I  wouldn't mind formatting my operating system just to achieve the results.

Comment: it's not your system... check array depth also... php also has a limit for that (I don't think it's that but still)

Comment: how do you check for array depth

Comment: when I use print_r($Results) it works but with json_encode($Results), it does not work. I think there is progress but very slow.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add character set to your pdo connection.

```
$Db = new PDO ( "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=recycle;charset=utf8",'root','' );
```

Comment: Correction: `utf8` without hyphen